# for a role-protected page, programmatically login user and load page

Tags: authentication

**Background**:

- I would like to use WordPress as the companion site to my course
- the course is administered through an LMS
- on WordPress, I am using the [Restrict Content](https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-content/) to protect pages that cannot be publicly accessible (mainly for copyright reasons), making them only available to users with the "subscriber" role

**Goal**

What I envisioned doing is providing a link from the LMS to some sort of "passthrough" script.  The link will provide a course-specific password as well as the link to a page via URL parameter passing, and when a user clicks on it, the script would automatically log on the user, and then redirect them to the role-restricted page.

I would **really** like to avoid having the students log into WordPress.

**Problem**

I started writing a simple PHP passthrough script using the [wp_signon](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) function, but am not familiar enough with WP to get it to work.

```
<?php

    require_once ("wp-includes/general-template.php");
    require_once ("wp-includes/template.php");
    require_once ("wp-includes/l10n.php");
    require_once ("wp-includes/formatting.php");
    require_once ("wp-includes/user.php");
    require_once ("wp-includes/pluggable.php");
    require_once ("wp-includes/plugin.php");
    require_once ("wp-includes/load.php");
    require_once ("wp-includes/class-wp-error.php");
    require_once ("wp-includes/pomo/translations.php");

    get_header();

    $creds = array(
            'user_login'    => 'student',
            'user_password' => 'password',
            'remember'      => true
    );

    $user = wp_signon($creds, false);

    if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
            var_dump($user);
    }

    else {
            wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
            do_action('set_current_user');
            echo "success!";
    }?>
```

When I try to run this with a user and password that works when I log into WP, I keep getting the following error:

```
object(WP_Error)#2 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["authentication_failed"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(78) "ERROR: Invalid username, email address or incorrect password." } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

I'm pretty certain I'm missing a critical piece, here, so I'm hoping someone can give me more guidance, or another way/plugin to approach this